# Unable to run terraform from Jenkins pipeline in vagrant virtual machine

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, terraform, pipeline

I have the below pipeline setup which uses terraform plugin to execute terraform.

Here is my environment. A centos7 vagrant vm has been installed terraform, jenkins using user vagrant. Terraform plugin is also installed to Jenkins. Terraform can be run manually. When terraform being used by pipeline, it is failed. Tried a couple of other ways to set up terraform path, all are failed.

Terraform is located at /usr/local/bin/terraform.

```
pipeline {

  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Set Terraform path') {
      steps {
        script {               
            def tfHome = tool name: 'terraform'
            env.PATH = "${tfHome}:${env.PATH}"
            // def tfhome = tool name: 'terraform', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation'
            // env.PATH = "${tfhome}:${env.PATH}"
            // def tfHome = tool name: 'terraform', type: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool'
            // env.PATH = "${tfHome}:${env.PATH}"
            echo "tfhome is ${tfhome}, env.PATH is ${env.PATH} "
        }
        // sh '/usr/local/bin/terraform -version'
        sh 'terraform -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is error message:

```
Failed Node Use a tool from a predefined Tool Installation

hudson.AbortException: No org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation named terraform found
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The terraform tool cannot be used by user jenkins. So I create a symlink pointing to terraform command.  The error is gone!